# How to commit foxpro dbf file into dbc?

Tags: sql, ms-access, foxpro

I managed to link a table in .dbc file to ms access.

The problem is that table1.dbf is somewhat locked and I cannot modify it so i copied the whole data and made a table for it. Now, i can update the table freely. After updating some rows, i exported it into a dbf file and replaced the original 'table1.dbf'. The problem is that when opening my program, it shows the following:

```
Table 'table1.dbf' is not marked as belonging to the 'dbases' database. 
Would you like to create the back link to mark it?
```

I understood that you have to commit the .dbf file before you can use it. Is there a way to commit the newly 'table1.dbf' without using foxpro? I managed to use visual studio but cannot find a tutorial on how to do it.

Comment: any idea regarding this? i'm stucked. I wanted to update values in the database but cannot go through this farther.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to "commit" the table here -- that's related to FoxPro's buffering mechanism, and not responsible for the error you have here.

What you're encountering is a quirk of the way FoxPro hacked the older xBase standard to allow "databases."  The DBC itself is a table that lists the names and fields of a set of other tables, in addition to some DBC-specific items like local views and whatnot.  To add a redundant check, the header of each table is additionally edited to include a relative path back to the DBC.

If that path is missing, FoxPro displays exactly that message you noted.  Clicking "Yes" should let FoxPro modify your table, so that you will no longer have the problem.

---

BTW, if you don't have Visual FoxPro and your application doens't contain an update capabilit, you have two options.

1: For **very simple** edits, you could just open the dbf in a descent text-editor (I've done it with NotePad++) and make the corrections manually.  So long as you produce rows and fields that are still the expected width, FoxPro won't even care that you made the changes manuall.  Of course, this is **very** error-prone, so backup before you attempt it and don't try thins for anything non-trivial.

2: Install the [Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839)  and have the provider mange your FoxPro data.  Rather than relying on the soon-to-be-removed ability of Access or Excel to edit DBF's that are mostly compatible with FoxPro, you can get a direct connection and perform most DDL and DML tasks yourself.

Comment: how do you modify the (.DBC) to add the table i just recently created? i already setup connection in visual studio? do i need to run a query to add a .dbf?

Comment: (For those not mmr who may happen upon this, you just connect to the DBC in the OLE DB provider and then issue FoxPro's native commands, like ADD TABLE.)

Answer (score 0):

First, can you confirm that you do or not have Visual Foxpro to work with the tables and database container?

You are obviously stuck in a not great, but not completely lost state, depending on the table structure.  Free tables (those not part of a database container -- .DBC), only allow column names to be up to 10 characters in length.  If part of a .DBC, then column names can be much longer.  Anyhow, when a table is originally part of the .dbc, the individual file header is stamped with the .dbc reference so it can automatically be opened when the table is opened.

What it SOUNDS like, is that when you have the database container opened and try to open the file, it does not find the header linkage and is asking how to resolve it.  The only way to back link is by opening the file exclusively and explicitly responding with Yes, add the back link.

As far as referencing the tables from Access, when you are making the connection string, it should point to the path where the tables are, not a specific table.  if you are working with a database container, it SHOULD automatically open when the file is accessed through the data provider.  You can additionally, connect, but the path should include the .DBC reference of the database container.

Hope this helps, and I'll keep an eye in case you have any follow-up issues.